# Leaving out data from XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to stackoverflow and also new to XML and XSLT.
You guys have helped me out with a lot of things already, but I need 1 little problem solved and I don't know how to explain so I just might not have the question or the answer about this topic...

Here's my problem:

I'm working on website for a bowling league which uses a special bowling league software. It outputs everything in PDF or in 1 big XML file.
It's a neat clean XML but it has these three lines of text (name of the league-abbreviation-date last updated) and I want to NOT display them after applying XSLT but I can't figure out the correct commands for this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet  type="text/xsl" href="scores.xsl"?>
<leagueScores>
    <name><![CDATA[Bowling Stones]]></name>
    <abbrev>WDOT</abbrev>
    <date>12-18-2014</date>
    <Rankings>
        <Rank>
            <Place>1</Place>
            <Team><![CDATA[Jaguars]]></Team>
            <VirtualRanking>2</VirtualRanking>
            <Points>36</Points>
            <Pins>9649</Pins>
            <YearAverage>1861</YearAverage>
        </Rank>
...
</leagueScores>
```

So I want to remove these :

```
<name><![CDATA[Bowling Stones Wommelgem Donderdag Trio's]]></name>
<afkorting>WDOT</afkorting>
<date>12-18-2014</date>
```

How should I do this?

This is the XSL file I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">



<xsl:template match="/leagueScores/Rankings">
<html>
  <body>
  <h1>Ploegenrangschikking</h1>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Plaats</th>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Virtueel</th>
      <th>Punten</th>
      <th>Kegels</th>
      <th>Jaar AVG</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Rank">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Place"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Team"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="VirtualRanking"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Points"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Pins"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="YearAverage"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/leagueScores/TeamScores">
<html>
  <body>
  <h1>Individuele Uitslagen</h1>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Naam</th>
      <th>G1</th>
      <th>G2</th>
      <th>G3</th>
      <th>TOT S</th>
      <th>TOT H</th>
      <th>HDC</th>
      <th>Hi Serie</th>
      <th>Hi Game</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="TeamScore/PlayerScores/PlayerScore">
    <xsl:if test="Game1 &gt; 0">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Game1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Game2"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Game3"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Tot"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="TotHDC"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="HDC"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="HighSerie"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="HighGame"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/leagueScores/Records">
<html>
  <body>
  <h1>Records</h1>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Categorie</th>
      <th>Naam</th>
      <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Record">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Category"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Score"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/leagueScores/MenIndividualScores">
<html>
  <body>
  <h1>Spelersrangschikking Mannen</h1>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Plaats</th>
      <th>Naam</th>
      <th>Games</th>
      <th>Kegels</th>
      <th>Vorig AVG</th>
      <th>Huidig AVG</th>
      <th>Totaal AVG</th>
      <th>Verschil</th>
      <th>HDP</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="MenIndividualScore">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Place"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Games"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Pins"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="previousAVG"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="currentAVG"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="totalAVG"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="AVGdiff"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="HDC"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/leagueScores/WomenIndividualScores">
<html>
  <body>
  <h1>Spelersrangschikking Vrouwen</h1>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Plaats</th>
      <th>Naam</th>
      <th>Games</th>
      <th>Kegels</th>
      <th>Vorig AVG</th>
      <th>Huidig AVG</th>
      <th>Totaal AVG</th>
      <th>Verschil</th>
      <th>HDP</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="WomenIndividualScore">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Place"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Games"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Pins"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="previousAVG"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="currentAVG"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="totalAVG"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="AVGdiff"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="HDC"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/leagueScores/Calendar">
<html>
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="Calendar">
    <tr>

    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/leagueScores/Infos">
<html>
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="Info">
    <tr>

    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/leagueScores/BestPerfomancesOfTheWeek">
<html>
  <body>
  <h1>Beste Weekprestaties</h1>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Categorie</th>
      <th>Naam</th>
      <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Performance">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Category"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Score"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/leagueScores/DayResults">
<html>
  <body>
  <h1>Matchuitslagen</h1>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>TOT HDC</th>
      <th>Punten</th>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>TOT HDC</th>
      <th>Punten</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="WomenIndividualScore">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Team1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="TotHDC1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Points1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Team2"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="TotHDC1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Points2"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance.
Rooster

Comment: Your upper document rather looks like the xml document to me with some random "text/xls" instruction added. Where is the real xsl-stylesheet? (scores.xsl)

Comment: Basically you would have to adapt/replace scores.xsl. And how to modify that stylesheet largely depends on the way it is written.

Comment: I was thinking I needed a seperate xsl:template for these three lines...

Comment: To answer your first question: the upper document is indeed the XML

Comment: Being a bit rusty and usually avoiding ``xsl:for-each``, I am kind of missing the ``xsl:apply-templates ... `` stuff. You have no template for ``/leagueScore``, so I wonder why those tags show.

Comment: are you saying they show because i tagged them somewhere in my XSL?

Comment: Now playing with the data I noticed, that you also did not specify ``<xsl:output method ="html"/>``. Maybe that is all it takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to remove these would be by adding an empty template matching them:

```
<xsl:template match="/leagueScores/name | /leagueScores/abbrev | /leagueScores/date"/>
```

---

The other way would avoid starting your template rules at:

```
<xsl:template match="/leagueScores/Rankings">
```

This causes the [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) to be applied to the `/` and `leagueScores` nodes - resulting in all their text nodes being copied to the output.

Try starting with:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

and then do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="leagueScores/Rankings/Rank">
```

instead of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Rank">
```

Comment: Wow, thanks!
That's the solution I needed. I will use the first option but in the future I'll make sure to apply my templates correctly!

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do it is:

```
<!-- only needed if transforming outside of a browser -->
<!-- <xsl:output method ="html"/>-->

<xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="/leagueScores/Rankings"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="/leagueScores/TeamScores"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="/leagueScores/Records"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="/leagueScores/MenIndividualScores"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="/leagueScores/WomenIndividualScores"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="/leagueScores/Calendar"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="/leagueScores/Infos"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="/leagueScores/BestPerfomancesOfTheWeek"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="/leagueScores/DayResults"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This way you need not change any other line in your stylesheet.

Output of given xml file for this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Ploegenrangschikking</h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Plaats</th>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Virtueel</th>
        <th>Punten</th>
        <th>Kegels</th>
        <th>Jaar AVG</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Jaguars</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>9649</td>
        <td>1861</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **1.** The output method has nothing to with the problem. **2.** Your suggestion would disable all the other templates whose match pattern begins with `/leagueScores/`.